# Getting page url based on component id and template priority

Tags: content-delivery

Is there any way to get page url based on component Id and template priority. I am using the following code to get the page url but this doesnot consider the template priority and return the first page found.

```
 var componentLink = new ComponentLink(componentTcmUri.PublicationId);
 var link = componentLink.GetLink(componentTcmUri.ItemId);
 var url = link.Url;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, the `GetLink(Int32)` and `GetLink(String)` methods of the `ComponentLink` class ignore template priorities. This is stated in the [documentation](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/Content%20Delivery%20ASP.NET%20API_tcm89-20005.chm) (CHM file).

You need to use a different overload - either of:

- `GetLink(Int32, Int32, Int32, String, String, Boolean, Boolean)`
- `GetLink(String, String, String, String, String, Boolean, Boolean)`

will consider template priorities.

If you do not have a Page URI (or a Template URI), you can use a null URI, like:

```
Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Linking.Link link = cl.GetLink("tcm:0-0-0", "tcm:69-1345", 
                                                           "tcm:0-0-0", "", 
                                                           "text", true, true);
```

Comment: Thanks David, As per documentation the component link picks up the link with highest priority. The other overloaded method requires page id as well which i don't have.

Comment: You can use "tcm:0-0-0" instead. Ideally though, do specify a valid page URI so that the link can be cached. This is the URI of the _current_ page, not the target, and if you don't care about proximity rules, use your home page URI.

Comment: I'm not sure if we mean the same thing here. The documentation for the GetLink methods with only an ID as a parameter state: Gets a URL to the first page that is found containing the requested targetComponentId. Template priorities are ignored for this specific method.

Comment: ... And I was just about to write, you can use a Null uri of "tcm:0-0-0", but Nuno beat me to it :) I will add the info to my answer

Comment: Thanks David/Nuno, Does the overloaded GetLink take care of template priorities automatically as i didn't find any parameter for template priority

Comment: Templating priority is automatic through the component linking API. You don't specify the priority you want to look for - The  API finds the page where the component is used with the highest priority component template it can find, excluding the template that you (may) specify. In the case of multiple uses of the same highest priority there is an algorithm that determines the most appropriate of those to link to

Comment: Thanks David, I can use the overloaded method to get the url with highest priority component template. Before marking the question as answered just two doubts. 1. In overloaded get link if i provide component id as tcm uri it gives url as null while if i provide id as integer it returns the url. 2. is there any way i can get the url based on template priority(rather than relying on the automatic logic of getting highest priority template (though in current scenario i only need the highest priority one))

Comment: 1. Sounds like you might be using the wrong publication context? My example, was tested on a working system and worked fine. 2. This is probably better asked as a separate question please.